# Controlling the value entered in the input field on react

Tags: reactjs

I have a function component that I control user login with react. According to the username and password entered in the input, if the value returned from the API is true, it redirects to another page, if false, it stays on the same page. When I press the button when the username and password are correct, the first value is It returns undefined, but when I press the button for the second time, it returns true and redirects to another page.

```js
export default function Login() {
  const [isUser, setUser] = useState();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const history = useHistory();
  let control;

  function userControl() {
    debugger;
    let userService = new UserService();
    userService.getUserControl(name, password).then((result) => setUser(result.data.data));
    console.log(isUser);

    if (isUser == true) {
      history.push('/oee');
    } else {
      setUser(false);
      setError('Kullanıcı Adınız veya Şifreniz Hatalı');
      control = errorMessage();
    }
  }

  function errorMessage() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Message negative>
          <Message.Header>{error}</Message.Header>
        </Message>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {control}
      <Grid textAlign="center" style={{ height: '70vh' }} verticalAlign="middle">
        <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450 }}>
          <Header as="h2" color="teal" textAlign="center">
            <Image style={{ height: 100, width: 200 }} src={ydclogo} />
          </Header>
          <Form size="large">
            <Segment stacked>
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                icon="user"
                iconPosition="left"
                placeholder="User Name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              />
              <Form.Input
                fluid
                icon="lock"
                iconPosition="left"
                placeholder="Password"
                type="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <Button color="teal" fluid size="large" onClick={userControl}>
                Login
              </Button>
            </Segment>
          </Form>
          <Message>L3 RAPORLAMA SİSTEMİ</Message>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the button is clicked for the first time, it enters the field below

```
 else 
    {
    
        setUser(false);
        setError('Kullanıcı Adınız veya Şifreniz Hatalı');
        control = errorMessage ();
    }
```

The name and password fields that I entered for the first time, I think, are empty passing to api, this is why, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```js
<Button color='teal' fluid size='large' onClick={()=>userControl()}>
   Login
</Button>
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: checkout values for name and password before sending to your service. If values are correct then checkout what you are storing in `setUser(result.data.data)`. Your condition indicates it should be bool value.